# Font not working in Safari and IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts, safari, font-face

I have 2 fonts on my website - GT-Pressura and NimbusSanExtD-Bla. Both are working fine in Chrome, Firefox and Microsoft Edge, but GT-Pressura do not working in Safari and IE.

I'm using following @font-face in my CSS:

```
    @font-face{font-family:GT-Pressura-Mono-Light;
src:url(../fonts/GT-Pressura-Mono-Light.woff2) format("woff2"),
url(../fonts/GT-Pressura-Mono-Light.woff) format("woff");
font-weight:400;
font-style:normal}
    
    @font-face{font-family:NimbusSanExtD-Bla;src:url(../fonts/NimbusSanExtD-Bla.woff2) format("woff2"),
url(../fonts/NimbusSanExtD-Bla.woff) format("woff");
font-weight:400;
font-style:normal}
```

What am I doing wrong in case of Safari or what I should do so GT-Pressura will start working in Safari and IE?

Thank in advance!

web-site is http://zodiac.film

## Things I've tried:

I have tried converting to `.eot` and `.otf` as read on here, I also tried everything [from here](https://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax) - and anything didn't work.

Comment: What solutions have you tried yourself? Why didn't they work? Have you explored other similar questions on here?

Comment: Yep, tried converting to .eot and .otf as read here, also tried everything from here - https://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/ - and anything didn't work. Why they didn't work - I don't know. If i knew i don't think i would ask this question here

Comment: thanks I updated your question.

Comment: Try and specify the font family like here, https://github.com/ColeTownsend/mesto/blob/master/fonts/font. Note how this does not use minus/dashes in the font family, but spaces.